# nginx 502 bad gateway, location of nginx.config

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am trying to upload my app to AWS (Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2) through Elastic Beanstalk. My app has been developed with Django 3.0. OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

I start with an empty Django project, this works fine with a green status health check, and Django admin works fine. When I add files from my app it throws the 502 bad gateway error. I have spent many days trying to fix this with no luck.

### var/log/nginx/error/log:

```
2021/06/29 15:29:42 [error] 4854#4854: *4084 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.20.250, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "35.176.238.136"
```

### django.config

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: FFfF_project.wsgi:application
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
        /static: static
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: FFfF_project.settings
        PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:"
```

### 01_packages.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    mariadb-devel: []
```

### requirements.txt

```
django==3.0
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
Pillow==8.2.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

### config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: FFfF-env
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  FFfF-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: FFfF_project
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: ff-KeyPair
  default_platform: Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: eu-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

I think the error is related to the nginx.config file, but I cannot find this file to either edit or modify. It is not on my system and I can't find it through the Elastic Beanstalk console. My extensive searching has led to many solutions using earlier versions of the AWS platform but virtually nothing on Amazon Linux 2. One solution appears to be using a config file with .platform/, this still needs access to the nginx/config file for modifying or over writing, but if I'm unable to find the nginx.config file I'm stumped!!!

As I understand the various documentations I don't need to install nginx as it an integral part of Elastic Beanstalk, maybe I've got that wrong!!

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to your problem? Btw, I'm leaving this here as an answer instead of a comment because I don't have enough rep to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this problem. The issue for us was the application load balancer.

This listeners / processes setup solved the problem for us.

[image: Listeners]

[image: Processes]